# OpenGL - Drawing Patterns

Tags: c++, opengl

Attched Image is what I am trying to do:

[image: Pattern I want]

However, my code is giving me the following pattern:

[image: CODE PATTERN]

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

```cpp
void drawPattern(float xPos, float yPos, float length){
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        // Drawing Square 
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(xPos + length, yPos);
        glVertex2f(xPos, yPos);
        glVertex2f(xPos , yPos + length);
        glVertex2f(xPos + length , yPos + length);
    glEnd();

    glColor3f(0,0,1);
    float halfPi = 0.5 * PI;
    //Drawing Bottom Left Circle
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (float angle = 0.0; angle < 90 * 0.01745329; angle += 0.01745329){
        glVertex2f( xPos + (length/2)*cos(angle), yPos + (length/2)*sin(angle));
    }
    glEnd();

    //Drawing Top Right Circle 
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (float angle = 0.0; angle < 90 * 0.01745329; angle += 0.01745329){
        glVertex2f( xPos + length/2 + (length/2)*cos(angle), yPos + length/2 + (length/2)*sin(angle));
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from, that you've to use the [line primitive type](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Line_primitives) `GL_LINE_STRIP` rather then `GL_LINE_LOOP`, what is already mentioned in an answer, the arc in the top right corner has the wrong direction.

This is because the center point of the arc has to be the top left (`xPos + length`, `yPos + length`) corner, rather than the center of the quad. Further the arc has to be draw in the bottom left segment. This is achieved by subtracting the sine and cosine terms:

```cpp
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
for (float angle = 0.0; angle < 90 * 0.01745329; angle += 0.01745329) {
    glVertex2f(
        xPos + length - (length/2)*cos(angle),
        yPos + length - (length/2)*sin(angle));
}
glEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be an idea to use GL_LINE_STRIP instead of GL_LINE_LOOP. The latter will always connect the end point to the start point, unlike the former.